# The sum of the different points on $x$-axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the sum of the different points on $x$-axis  and that intersect with the two curves :

$$x^2=x+y+4 , y^2=y-15x+36$$

Comment: Looks like you need to solve the system. Try to find $y$ in terms of $x$ from the first equation, and plug into the second one.

Comment: Set $y=0$, solve both for $x$, add the results. (Assuming I interpreted your question correctly.)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have said, we set $y=0$. For the curve $y^2=-15x+36$, we get $x=36/15$. For the curve $x^2=x+y+4$ we get $x^2-x-4=0$.

By the Rational Roots Theorem, the only conceivable rational roots of $x^2-x-4=0$ are *integers* that divide $4$. None of these is in fact a root, but that is irrelevant,  the point is that $36/15$ cannot be a root of $x^2-x-4=0$.

Now we still need the sum of the (real) roots of $x^2-x-4=0$. It is easy to see that there are in fact two real roots. We could compute them, using the Quadratic Formula, and then add. But in general the sum of the roots of $x^2+ax+b=0$ is $-a$. So the sum of the roots of $x^2-x-4=0$ is $1$. Add that to $36/15$.

**Remark:** Consider the polynomial equation $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n=0$, where $a_0\ne 0$. Then the sum of all the roots of the equation in the complex numbers is $-a_1/a_0$. In this formula, a root of multiplicity greater than $1$ counts as many times as it occurs. For example, $x^2-6x+9=0$ as a "double root" at $x=3$. The formula predicts, correctly, that the sum of the roots is $-(-6)$.

Comment: Is the second curve a function ?

Comment: @MohammedAl-mubark: In the second curve, $y$ is not a function of $x$, but $x$ is a function of $y$.

Comment: Ok ,but is there any relationship between the two curves if we draw them on the plane ?

Comment: They are both parabolas, maybe even closely related parabolas.